# SQL Select - Where search term contains '.'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do an MySQL SELECT query on a table that looks a bit like this:

```
-------------------------------
|  id  |  domain      | etc...
|------+--------------+--------
|  1   |  dev.howmuch |
|------+--------------+--------
|  2   |  devhowmuch  |
```

At the moment I'm just trying to do the simple

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_swad_apps` WHERE `domain` = 'devhowmuch'
```

Which works fine, however as soon as I try

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_swad_apps` WHERE `domain` = 'dev.howmuch'
```

It returns no results, my guessing is that it's trying to treat the fullstop as a wildcard or as a table reference (`table`.`field`).

How can I get it to query purely as a string?  Thanks

**EDIT:** I appreciate the help guys but none of these are working:
There are no trailing or leading spaces.  If I try `LIKE '%howmuch%'` both results turn up, if I do `LIKE '%.howmuch%'` nothing comes up.

**hex(domain) result as requested:**

```
1 dev.howmuch 646576A9686F776D756368
2 devhowmuch 646576686F776D756368
```

Comment: Please run `SELECT id, domain, hex(domain) FROM tbl_swad_apps` and update the question with the results. There's no such thing as "wildcards" in the `=` operator and, of course, SQL does not look for table names inside string literals. It might also help to see the exact table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell contains this:

```
d  e  v  .  h  o  w  m  u  c  h
64 65 76 A9 68 6F 77 6D 75 63 68
```

[Full stop](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2e/index.htm) should probably be `2E` (it's a 7-bit ASCII character so it's the same byte in many encodings, including UTF-8):

```
mysql> SELECT HEX('.');
+----------+
| HEX('.') |
+----------+
| 2E       |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But you have `A9`. That's not a 7-bit ASCII character and we don't know what encoding your data uses so we can't tell what it is (but it's clearly not a dot). In ISO-8859-1 and Windows-1252 it'd be a copyright symbol (©). In UTF-8 it'd be an invalid character, typically displayed as [REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) (�) by many clients.

Comment: This is really strange, if I do the same `HEX('.')` command I get '2E' like you.  But whenever I query the table itself I get A9. No matter how many times I update (whether through phpmyadmin or the terminal)

Comment: Why did you `UNHEX` 2A instead of A9?  For A9 I get ©.

Comment: I wondered that, but it did help.  I did an insert query using `UNHEX` and that has solved the issue.  Really not sure why this happened in the first place but it was always showing 'dev.howmuch' in any other query results... odd.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation. I mistyped the hex code and also wrote a quick and terribly misguided analysis. I've just (hopefully) improved the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not honest.

There is no problem with period.

Here is a proof:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e380/1

The problem should be with the real value in the table that include some nonprinting characters.

So you can choose - fix the value in the table.

Or use other query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_swad_apps` WHERE `domain` LIKE '%dev.howmuch%';
```

or even:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_swad_apps` WHERE `domain` LIKE '%dev%.%howmuch%';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e380/4

Comment: Yeah, there's probably a space at the end or something.

Comment: Nope. There are no spaces, I see it working in your fiddle, but not in my phpmyadmin. How you see it in my question is exactly how it is in my setup

Comment: try to `SELECT *, LENGTH(domain) FROM \`tbl_swad_apps\`` and check in length is 11

Answer (score 0):

If there might be leading/trailing spaces you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_swad_apps` WHERE `domain` = LTRIM(RTRIM('dev.howmuch'))
```